# "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is Installed" How do I find the problem code?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have a site and since updating to 4.5 it has a very subtle display bug that seems jQuery related (full bleed images have a white border that snaps away into correctness when you resize window).

The theme hasn't been updated since 2014.

The only lead we have is this in the console:

`JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.0`

My understanding is that this indicates some of the jQuery in the plugins or theme is using old API's and this adds compatibility.

[Related question about silencing the message, NOT WHAT I NEED.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224661/annoying-jqmigrate-migrate-is-in-console-after-update-to-wp-4-5)

**How can I figure out the code that's causing it?**

I suspect that the display problem is related, and even if it isn't I figure I should start there either way.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrate message is merely informational. It isn't a warning or error.

It is displayed unconditionally whenever respective script is loaded. In current WP version it is loaded whenever `jquery` handle is requested by anything, alongside `jquery-core`.