# Can't get rid of JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.3.2. Manually updated all the libralies and site. 5.8.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, debug

Answers I found here are about the older versions of WordPress when it were transitioning into a new version of jQuery. (This is version 5.8.2)

Since the one from WordPress is not logging active, I put
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.3.2.js"></script>` and manually checked each page.

I fixed the bind/unbind, onload, onclick deprecated functions until no warnings shows up on console. After I removed my script tag and put WordPress's JQmigrate back (I had a plugin disabled WordPress's JQmigrate) it's still showing up on console. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Annoying "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is..." in console after update to WordPress 4.5](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224661/annoying-jqmigrate-migrate-is-in-console-after-update-to-wordpress-4-5)

Comment: I'm not sure. I dug deeper and found that a few of wp core files still need jqmigrate. Some websites running 5.8.2 has this console log and some don't. I haven't been following wp dev scene, so perhaps it's normal.